# How to use Google stock chart in React JS

Tags: reactjs, charts, apexcharts, react-google-charts

This is a google chart I need such a chart in my react js project I have daily data so I will start the timeline in one month. If anyone has any answers, please do let me know. Gratitude.

```
exampaleData = {[dateInTimeStamp, price], [dateInTimeStamp, price]}
```

[Google chart image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kmOTC.png)